# How to install json extension for PHP 7 on CentOS?

Tags: linux, laravel, centos, composer-php, php-7

On my server I had PHP 5 installed previously .I upgraded it to PHP 7 by following the steps from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7) But when I try to install the composer for the using laravel ,it shows

```
The json extension is missing.Install it or recompile php without --disable-json"
```

Then I tried installing the json extension on the server ,it shows the following error

```
Error: php70u-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.5.38-8.el7.remi.x86_64
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.5.38-8.el7.remi.x86_64
```

After hours of searching the internet, I couldn't still find any solution. Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install JSON extension for PHP 7 in centos using below command.

```
sudo yum install php70u-json
```

Comment: thanks !!! this solved my problem .But now the composer commands aren't executed.It shows command not found ,can you please help ?

Comment: Thanks ! For my version I executed    yum install php-json

Answer (score 0):

You can install JSON extension for PHP 7 in centos using below command:

```
yum install php-json
```

…on centos 8 running php 7.2